# LaTeX error with fig.cap in knitr and Sweave

Tags: latex, knitr, sweave, figure

The following code causes a "Runaway argument" error in LaTeX after knitr has run:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<fig.cap="This causes \\texttt{problems.}">>=
plot(1:10,10:1)
@

\end{document}
```

It's not obvious why, so I hope this helps others who may encounter this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises because, as stated in ["Power of Graphics in knitr"](https://bitbucket.org/stat/knitr/downloads/knitr-graphics.pdf)

> The default short caption is extracted from the caption by truncating it at the first period
>   or colon or semi-colon.

Thus, the .tex file produced by knitting the above example contains the following

```
\caption[This causes \texttt{problems]{This causes \texttt{problems.}
```

The solution is to supply a short caption that is not truncated prematurely, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<fig.cap="This causes \\texttt{no problems.}", fig.scap="This causes \\texttt{no problems.}">>=
plot(1:10,10:1)
@

\end{document}
```

Many, many thanks to Yihui Xie for massively increasing my productivity and the reusability of my code!

Comment: thanks for answering your own question; I was surprised by this potential problem

Comment: Thank YOU Yihui (I'm kind of glad it wasn't a newbie issue!)

Comment: no, it was not; it is a hole that I was unaware of and I cannot do much about it, either, since it would involve parsing LaTeX, which will be ugly to do in R